# How to produce kernel panic with power button on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, panic

I would like to debug a kext with a target MacBook Pro, Mountain Lion. How could I setup the computer to produce a kernel panic on power button press?

I have tried sudo nvram boot-args="debug=0x144 -v", as I used on an iMac but without success.

I would appreciate any suggestions or links to the docs.

Comment: MacBook Pro doesn't have a RJ45 ethernet connector, it cannot be accessed with a kernel debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which "MacBook Pro" model you're using.  A built-in ethernet port isn't the only way to do two machine debugging anymore.

You need to reboot after changing nvram, e.g.

```
sudo nvram boot-args="debug=0x144 -v"
sudo reboot
```

Also, see the [video](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/707xfx3xysb4yyrvtxbbu6t9fono/707/707-HD.mov?dl=1) and [PDF](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/707xfx3xysb4yyrvtxbbu6t9fono/707/707.pdf?dl=1) from WWDC 2013 "What's New in Kext Development"